# The use of Thread.Sleep(0) and Join()

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am reading a book about multithreading programs and I found this small example :

```
public static class Program
    {
        public static void ThreadMethod()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(“ThreadProc: {0}”, i);
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
            t.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(“Main thread: Do some work.”);
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
            t.Join();
        }
    }
```

I've got too many questions in mind:

1) What's the use of **Thread.Sleep(0)** , I mean, I've tried the two cases : with or without **Thread.Sleep(0)**, no big difference in runtime

2) Is **t.Join()** really usefull here, since it is in the end of the **Main** method ?

Comment: `t.Join()` is required there, otherwise a program may halt with `ThreadMethod()` not finished its execution.

Comment: What's the book? I want to know so I don't recommend it. Thread.Sleep(0) is useless AFAIK.

Comment: On a single core machine you would see a very different behavior between with the sleep and without. @JohnSaunders it forces a context switch, so on a single core machine it can have its uses.

Comment: @John Saunders : Exam Ref 70-483: Programming in C#

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I did not know [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx): "the thread relinquishes the remainder of its time slice to any thread of equal priority that is ready to run"

Comment: A book which presents that code without clearly explaining the purpose of the join and wait is not a book I should like a beginner to learn from.

Comment: @johnsaunders see http://blog.coverity.com/2014/02/12/how-does-locking-work for a more well motivated use of a zero sleep

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Thread.Sleep(0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will yield to other threads that don't have lower priority then yours:

> If the value of the millisecondsTimeout argument is zero, the thread relinquishes the remainder of its time slice to any thread of equal priority that is ready to run. If there are no other threads of equal priority that are ready to run, execution of the current thread is not suspended.

So in case of this example it is something that tries to make threads run at approximately equal pace.

The [`Thread.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) usage suggests that it is needed not to end your program before your threads finish their work. However, as [Scott Chamberlain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80274/scott-chamberlain) points out, by default [`IsBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is `false` so your threads are *foreground* threads, and will keep the program running by themselves until they've finished their work. If your program had something more to do, and usually has, that needs the results of threads' work then the `Join` call would really be essential.

Try setting the `IsBackground` property to different values, and experiment with removing the `Join` call to see what happens.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Seems you're right, thanks for pointing that out. I've added this information :)